# nginx: restrict access to everything with basic_auth except for a specific page

Tags: authentication, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

This is the original nginx configuration I have here, working fine:

```
  server {

    listen 8080; # http

    # Forward requests to our node app at port 8082
    #
    location /mui {
        # Remove the '/mui' portion of the path (and any extraneous trailing slash)
        rewrite ^/mui/?(.*)$    /$1;     break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location  / {
      # We also rewrite the Java servlet urls to move additional, 'RESTful' path elements
      # to a url query parameter named '_path_suffix'
      #
      rewrite ^/(.*)$    /server?_path_suffix=$1;     break;
      proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081;
      proxy_redirect     off;
    }
  }
```

I want to add basic authentication to everything - EXCEPT for one single page... `/mui/river`

If I include the basic authentication lines in the server block, and put the `auth_basic off` inside `location /mui` block, it works as expected for this configuration (it requires authentication for `/` but not for `/mui`):

```
  server {

    listen 8080; # http

    auth_basic           "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/ngnix/.htpasswd;


    # Forward requests to our node app at port 8082
    #
    location /mui {
        # Remove the '/mui' portion of the path (and any extraneous trailing slash)
        rewrite ^/mui/?(.*)$    /$1;     break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        auth_basic off;
    }

    location  / {
      # We also rewrite the Java servlet urls to move additional, 'RESTful' path elements
      # to a url query parameter named '_path_suffix'
      #
      rewrite ^/(.*)$    /server?_path_suffix=$1;     break;
      proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081;
      proxy_redirect     off;
    }
  }
```

Almost perfect. Next step would be to make it request authentication for everything inside `/mui`, except for page `/mui/river`.

That's where my problem is... I tried the following, and when I reach `/mui/river` it still requires authentication...

```
server {

    listen 8080; # http

    auth_basic           "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/ngnix/.htpasswd;



    location = /mui/river {
      rewrite ^/mui/?(.*)$    /$1;     break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        auth_basic off;
    }

    # Forward requests to our node app at port 8082
    #
    location /mui {
        # Remove the '/mui' portion of the path (and any extraneous trailing slash)
        rewrite ^/mui/?(.*)$    /$1;     break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location  / {
      # We also rewrite the Java servlet urls to move additional, 'RESTful' path elements
      # to a url query parameter named '_path_suffix'
      #
      rewrite ^/(.*)$    /server?_path_suffix=$1;     break;
      proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081;
      proxy_redirect     off;
    }
  }
```

How can I open access only for `/mui/river`?

Update:
This is my latest attempt, still not working - still blocking everything. Note that I also tried to change the rewrite line:

```
 server {
    listen 8080; # http

    # Forward requests to our node app at port 8082
    #

 location = /mui/river {
         rewrite ^/mui/river?(.*)$    /river$1;     break;
         auth_basic off;
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

   location /mui {
        # Remove the '/mui' portion of the path (and any extraneous trailing slash)
        rewrite ^/mui/?(.*)$    /$1;     break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        auth_basic           "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/ngnix/.htpasswd;
    }

    location  / {
      # The Java servlet is always assumed to be named 'server', so add that to the path.
      #
      # We also rewrite the Java servlet urls to move additional, 'RESTful' path elements
      # to a url query parameter named '_path_suffix'
      #
      rewrite ^/(.*)$    /server?_path_suffix=$1;     break;
      proxy_pass         http://localhost:8081;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      auth_basic           "Restricted Area";
      auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now your basic auth is set at the server level (inside the `server {...}` block), so it will apply to *all* location blocks.

If you want to protect everything *except* `/mui/river`, move the following 2 lines inside the `location /mui {...}` and `location  / {...}` you wish to protect:

```
auth_basic "Restricted Area";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/ngnix/.htpasswd;
```

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/

Comment: I tried that too... I'm updating my question to also show my latest attempt (still not working, still blocking everything) - note I also tried to change the rewrite line.